# Conventional screen px width standard for HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, screen-resolution

Is there a conventional screen width that is considered to be the maximum, i.e. triggers a horizontal scroll bar when exceeded?

E.g. my laptop display resolution is 1600x900 so when I set the main content div width to be 1100 with some margins on either side, it looks approximately like the screen you are looking at now.

But I am concerned if it may spill over widthwise on smaller display resolutions.  Should I take something less than 1600 as my maximum and what should it be?

Comment: Is it really that big an issue? If it is you can use .js to check and switch css files based on detection... You can probably also do browser detection for mobile browsers... Or better still how about not using px and using %...?

Answer (score 0):

That's really high sounding to me. I wouldn't make a layout larger than 800px if I don't ever want it to scroll over. If I'm being more lenient 900 or 950px is ok. I'm including margins.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use %? It will never have scroll issues... you just need to detect if background image scaling is available (css3)

The only issue I have ever had with % is the background image scale issue... with css3 this is solved so you could base your entire design around %

Answer (score 0):

use a percentage (with a three column/div layout) and a centre column with the additional attribute of max-width:960px;...
That's pretty much an industry standard.
Here's a really good layout guide with a responsive (elastic) grid system:  http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/